# Git staging to working directory?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset

I have a question concerning the `git reset` command:

```
git reset .
git reset HEAD .
```

What is the difference between the two commands? Are making same changes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does exactly the same. If you omit the commit id, it will default to HEAD.

Answer (score 1):

1. Git Reset: to undo commits:

   - --soft (does not change stage index or working directory)
   - --mixed (default) (changes stage index to match repository)
   - --hard (change stage index and working directory)

Example: git reset "hashValueOfAnyCommit"

2. Git Reset HEAD: Unstage file from your stage

Comment: Doesn't answers the OP's question. But is quite useful. **Read the whole question (including details) before leaving an answer**, bud.